# Using matlab to arrange and sort data

Tags: matlab

My data is an excel file with two columns in this format:

```
Date           Type
3/12/06        A
3/12/06        B
3/12/06        B
3/12/06        C
6/01/07        A
6/01/07        A
8/01/07        B
...
```

Column A are dates and can be repeated while column B are types of observations on these dates.

In MATLAB I want to plot each type as a function of time, however first I need to arrange my data. There are often multiple identical rows that correspond to multiple observations of the same type on the same date. So I think first I need to count how many times a certain type occurred on the same day?

Any help would be great! I'm still at the stage of trying to read the dates in the correct format...

Comment: Why do you want to count the repeated data? How do you want to show it in a plot?

Comment: @Adiel I would like a line plot of the number of observations as a function of time for each type

Comment: A stacked bar plot of each type over time would also work I think

Comment: How are you trying to read this data into Matlab? Show us any code you've tried...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution: I replace each type and each date with a specific index and then I use accumarray in order to create a 2D pivot table. You can also directly use the function pivot table from excel.

```
% We load the xls file.
[~,txt] = xlsread('test.xls');
% We delete the header:
txt(1,:) = [];
% Value and index for the date:
[val_d,~,ind_d] = unique(txt(:,1));
% Value and index for the type:
[val_c,~,ind_c] = unique(txt(:,2));
% We use accumarray to create a pivot table that count each occurence.
acc = accumarray([ind_d,ind_c],1)

% Then we simply plot the result:
dateFormat = 'dd/mm/yy';   
for i = 1:length(val_c);
  subplot(1,length(val_c),i)
  bar(datenum(val_d,dateFormat),acc(:,i),1) % easier to deal with datenum
  datetick('x',dateFormat)
  xlabel('Date')
  ylabel([val_c{i},' count'])
  ylim([0,3])
end
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @obchardon for this example! I'm getting this error `Error using datenum (line 181) DATENUM failed. Caused by: Error using dtstr2dtnummx Failed to convert from text to date number.` I'm using Matlab 2016b